# Is it a bad idea to use google cloud storage on heroku deployed projects?

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So my app is deployed on Heroku and I'm using a google cloud storage bucket to handle uploads.

Wouldn't communication from my app to google cloud platform be slow compared to using S3 given the fact that Heroku is on top of AWS infrastructure?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the traffic would be routed over the internet. I would be more worried about the network pricing than performance, unless you have very high performance requirements.

Both AWS and GCP have free ingress pricing, and they both charge you if you move data off their platform. It's typically around 10x more expensive to transfer data out of a cloud than say between regions in a cloud. Here's the price list for GCS: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress